# Connecting to multiple collections in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to access two collections of my MongoDB for my React app. I have constructed two API_URLs:

```js
const API_URL = window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ? 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/Sessions' : 'production-url-here'

const API_URL1 = window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ? 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/members' : 'production-url-here'
```

The sessions collection is returned with raw data when I put the url into my browser but the members URL returns a "not found" message.

I have mirrored my server and client side code of the sessions collection for my members collection and Im unsure as to what the issue is.

Here is the code for members.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const Joi = require("joi");

const db = require('../db');
const members = db.get('members');

//Defining the schema for the backend.
const schema1 = Joi.object().keys({
    name:   Joi.string().min(1).max(100).required(),
    bio:   Joi.string().min(1).max(500).required(),
    latitude:    Joi.number().required(),
    longitude:   Joi.number().required()
});

const router = express.Router();

//Gets all sessions that are found within the DB.
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  members
  .find()
  .then(allmembers =>{
      res.json(allmembers);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the code for Sessions.js :

```js
const express = require('express');
const Joi = require("joi");

const db = require('../db');
const Sessions = db.get('Sessions');

//Defining the schema for the backend.
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    event:   Joi.string().min(1).max(100).required(),
    venue:   Joi.string().min(1).max(500).required(),
    address: Joi.string().min(1).max(100).required(),
    dtstart: Joi.string().required(),
    dtend:   Joi.string().required(),
    latitude:    Joi.number().required(),
    longitude:   Joi.number().required()
});

const router = express.Router();

//Gets all sessions that are found within the DB.
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Sessions
  .find()
  .then(allSessions =>{
      res.json(allSessions);
    });
});
//POST for when no errors are produced.
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const result = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);
  if (result.error == null) {
//Removes the need to write eg) req.body.name below.
    const { event, venue, address, latitude, longitude, dtstart, dtend,} = req.body;
    const Session = {
      event,
      venue,
      address,
      dtstart,
      dtend,
      latitude,
      longitude,
      date: new Date()
     };
   Sessions.insert(Session).then(insertedMessage => {
         res.json(insertedMessage);
   });
 }
else {
  next(result.error);
   }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Frontend code:

```react
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import L from 'leaflet';
import Joi from 'joi';
//import only modules needed or error.
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import { Card, CardTitle, CardText } from 'reactstrap';
import {Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import Chart from './components/Chart';


var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/purepng.com-harpharpstringedsoundboardfingersmodern-1421526538276nepuu.png',
    iconSize: [25, 51],
    iconAnchor: [12.5, 51],
    popupAnchor: [0, -51],
    draggable: true,
});
//Joi creates the schema for validation
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    event: Joi.string().min(1).max(100).required(),
    venue: Joi.string().min(1).max(500).required(),
    address: Joi.string().min(1).max(100).required(),
    dtstart: Joi.string().required(),
    dtend:   Joi.string().required()
});

const schema1 = Joi.object().keys({
    name:   Joi.string().min(1).max(100).required(),
    bio:   Joi.string().min(1).max(500).required(),
    latitude:    Joi.number().required(),
    longitude:   Joi.number().required()
});

//URL declaration, if hostname is localhost, request backend. otherwise URL.
const API_URL = window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ? 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/Sessions' : 'production-url-here'
const API_URL1 = window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ? 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/members' : 'production-url-here'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    location: {
        lat: 51.505,
        lng: -0.09,
 },
 UserslocationFound: false,
   zoom: 12,
   /* Monitors the state of the users inputs (detects changes). */
   UsersSession: {
     event: '',
     venue: '',
     address: '',
     dtstart: '',
     dtend: ''
   },
   Sessions: [],
   members: []
 }
componentDidMount() {
  //Grabs the markers from the Thesession API to be displayed.
  fetch(API_URL)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(Sessions => {
       this.setState({
         Sessions
       });
     });

     fetch(API_URL1)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(members => {
          this.setState({
            members
          });
        });

  /*Asks user for location via google alert. */
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    this.setState({
      location: {
        lat:  position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      },
      UserslocationFound: true,
      zoom: 15,
      draggable: true
    });
  }, () => {
    console.log("Location not given ");
    fetch('https://ipapi.co/json')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(location => {
          console.log(location);
          this.setState({
            location: {
              lat:  location.latitude,
              lng: location.longitude
            },
            UserslocationFound: true,
            zoom: 15
          });
      });
});
}

formSubmitted = (event) => {
/* prevents the page from refreshing on submit. */
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.UsersSession);
  const UsersSession = {
    event: this.state.UsersSession.event,
    venue: this.state.UsersSession.venue,
    address: this.state.UsersSession.address,
    dtstart: this.state.UsersSession.dtstart,
    dtend: this.state.UsersSession.dtend
  };
  //importing Joi to get the result through validation of the inputs with the schema.
  const result = Joi.validate(UsersSession, schema);
  if(!result.error) {
//fetching against API_URL
    fetch(API_URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',

      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        ...UsersSession,
        latitude: this.state.location.lat,
        longitude: this.state.location.lng,
      })
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(Sessions => {
      console.log(Sessions)
    });
  }
}

/*Updates the state on UsersSession */
valueChanged = (event) => {
  /*declaring event.target as it throws errors in chrome */
  const { name,value } = event.target;
  /*Sets usersSession to be the value defined in inputs */
   this.setState((prevState) => ({
     UsersSession: {
       ...prevState.UsersSession,
       [name]: value
     }
   }))
}
//Sharing of code between React components
  render() {
     const position = [this.state.location.lat, this.state.location.lng]
    return (
      <div className ="map">
      <Map className ="map" center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
      /* tile imported to use over leafletjs*/
         <TileLayer
           attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
           url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
         />

         /* displays marker for when users location is given/found */
         { this.state.UserslocationFound ?

         <Marker
                position={position}
                icon={myIcon}>
         </Marker> : ''

         }
         {this.state.Sessions.map(UsersSession => (
           <Marker
                   position={[UsersSession.latitude, UsersSession.longitude]}
                   icon={myIcon} >
              <Popup>
              <em>{UsersSession.event}, </em>
                  {UsersSession.venue} {'\n'}

                  <Button color="primary" size="sm">More info</Button>
                  <Chart/>
              </Popup>
           </Marker>
         ))}

         {this.state.members.map(Users => (
           <Marker
                   position={[Users.latitude, Users.longitude]}
                   icon={myIcon} >
              <Popup>
              <em>{Users.name}, </em>
                  {Users.bio} {'\n'}

                  <Button color="primary" size="sm">More info</Button>
                  <Chart/>
              </Popup>
           </Marker>
         ))}
       </Map>
       <Card body className="message-form">
        <CardTitle>Welcome to TradMap!</CardTitle>
        <CardText>Please input the details of your Session below.</CardText>
        <Form onSubmit={this.formSubmitted}>
       <FormGroup>
         <Label for="name">Session Title</Label>
         <Input
         /*when the state changes */
           onChange={this.valueChanged}
           type="text"
           name="event"
           id="event"
           placeholder="..." />

           <Label for="startDate">Start Date</Label>
           <Input
             onChange={this.valueChanged}
             type="date"
             name="dtstart"
             id="dtstart" />

          <Label for="EndDate"> End Date </Label>
             <Input
               onChange={this.valueChanged}
               type="date"
               name="dtend"
               id="dtend" />

               <Label for="venue">Session Venue</Label>
               <Input
                 onChange={this.valueChanged}
                 type="textarea"
                 name="venue"
                 id="venue"
                 placeholder="..." />

               <Label for="Address">Session Address</Label>
               <Input
                 onChange={this.valueChanged}
                 type="textarea"
                 name="address"
                 id="address"
                 placeholder="..." />
      </FormGroup>

       <Button type ="submit" color="info" disabled={!this.state.UserslocationFound}>submit</Button>
       </Form>
      </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: How/where do you use & put together the stuff that's exported from `members.js` and `Sessions.js`?

Comment: As its a react app, they are rendered in my app.js folder. When I change my API_URL1 to be mapped to the Sessions collection, the code compiles and the map is displayed but the data returned is not accurate. This issue seems to be pointing to the actual directory of members as I can't access it through my browser or within the code.

Comment: I actually think the fact that this is a React app doesn't matter, as that's a frontend concern. I believe all of the code you put in your original question is backend code (to be more specific, `express`-related). Where do you `require('./members.js')` and `require('./Sessions.js')`, and how do you use that code? I have a suspicion that you have a line like `app.use(Sessions)` somewhere, but not `app.use(members)` (where `Sessions` and `members` refer to each respective exported router).

Comment: I am going to edit the question to include my frontend code. That might make a bit more sense of my issue. in my two backend files, I am requiring the db and then using db.get('Sessions') to get the collection. Im then using it again after its been passed from backend to front (see code above)

Comment: Are you testing this for `localhost` or for a production server? I see your frontend code, but I still think this is a backend concern (given that the backend controls whether `404 Not Found` is sent). Or, maybe I'm just misunderstanding the issue at hand ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: for Localhost. The members collection is not even coming up through my localhost in my browser. So not only am I unable to view the collection, I am unable to reference it in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was referencing the Members collection on the server side. I had not referenced it within the index.js file of the api directory:

```js
const Members = require('./Members');

router.use('/Members', Members);
```

This then allowed for my collection to be referenced in my front-end and to be accessed through localhost.